# MinecraftForge 1.12 readImagetoBuffer error

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a Minecraft mod in intellij with the recommended version of 1.12.2 forge. When i try to run the client, it crashes with an error.

The error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer

net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.readImageToBuffer(line:841)
```

Im using java 8, because with java 12 I get some errors.

This error is not because of a mod, im not coding yet, just testing that MC runs correctly

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide more detail in your question, ideally including some description of what the mod does and a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Yeah, it is just minecraft without anything changed. I was just testing if minecraft forge 1.12.2 ran

Comment: I would suspect this is a bug with forge itself. Try asking on their support forums

Comment: Yeah... Their support forum i think doesnt support 1.12 because i joined Their discord and they are all toxic

Comment: I got it error also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compiled with Java 9 or newer despite trying to to run on Java 8. Clear all of your cache and build files, and make sure you use Java 8 to rebuild.

Comment: Could u tell me How can i see the jdk im using to compile? Because i have only used 1.8 i think...